# svn "did not expect ... to be working copy root"

Tags: svn

I was trying out branching. First i switched to the branch and then now i switch back to trunk but am unable to commit, it says:

```
svn: Commit failed (details follow):
svn: Did not expect '/home/repo/proj/src/qc' to be a working copy root
```

please help o.o

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can find your answer in [this page](http://mail-archives.apache.org/mod_mbox/subversion-dev/201002.mbox/%3C4B73FDEB.8060603@elego.de%3E).

Comment: thank you for your response! I fixed it! I just changed some lines in the .svn/entries 
some lines are not updated, it still keeps the branches folder as the main wc i think :D

Comment: There is an explanation of how the error could occur, but no answer  on how to resolve it (-1) :(